# Why does SQL Join find two dissimilar length strings equal?

Tags: sql, join, equals, foxpro

I have created a query that uses a left join. For reasons I don't understand it will join two dissimilar length strings as if they are equal. An example would be:

```
Left column = "351-561"
Right Column = "351-561-35C"
Result = Joined as equal.
```

My workaround has been to right pad the strings to the same length. I don't understand though why those two strings would be treated as equal.

Is there some mechanism in the syntax that would change that behavior?

D.

Comment: What database product and version?

Comment: What data types are they? Can you edit your post to include the sql?

Comment: they are not equal at all. could you show your data and your query?

Comment: The only reason I could think of would be if the right column was being implicitly cast to `char(7)` not sure of any product that would do that.

Comment: Is one of the tables in the join a temp table with the length set to 7 causing the value to be truncated?

Comment: @Martin - And what a "feature" that would be. Sign me up for that product ;->

Comment: My Dev environment is Visual Fox Pro V9. I'll post my query below.  `SELECT * ;
FROM T2 ;
LEFT JOIN Temp2 T3 ;
ON PADr(ALLTRIM(T2.casenumber),20," ") = PADr(ALLTRIM(T3.casenum),20," ") ;
INTO CURSOR JRreport`

Comment: You should change it to `INNER JOIN`. I am thinking you are seeing all records from T2 in the first few columns right?

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi no not at all Left table has 5608 records and Right table has 60K records. The end result is 6008 records. I used left join because i wanted all left records regardless of a match to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may well need to use the `==` operator in [Visual Fox Pro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z694sba%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: WTF! That was the problem. Thanks Martin. I sure don't get why a single = would change the behavior in that way. I would think that if it was interpreted as an assignment operator I would get WAY more matches than just the dissimilar length strings. Hmmph. Anyway thanks for setting me straight. D.

Comment: @Donovan - WTF indeed. I don't think it treats it as assignment I think the default behaviour is just odd. `SET ANSI ON` might also work from looking at [this KB article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx5eyfsx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual FoxPro, the = operator means equal.  The == operator means "exactly equal".  In other words, the == operator compares the size and value of each expression.  For example:

```
* Returns .T. because the first 3 characters on the left match the right.
? "123" = "12345"

* Returns .F. because the expression sizes are not equal.
? "123" == "12345"
```

That being said, the only reason I can think a JOIN would fail is because the columns you are joining on are not the same size.  For example, this query only returns the 555-1234 record because a CHAR column is automatically padded right with spaces.

```
CREATE CURSOR "MyLeft" (LeftPK I, LeftCode C(20))
INSERT INTO "MyLeft" VALUES(1, "351-561")
INSERT INTO "MyLeft" VALUES(2, "555-1234")

CREATE CURSOR "MyRight" (RightPK I, RightCode C(20))
INSERT INTO "MyRight" VALUES(1, "351-561-35C")
INSERT INTO "MyRight" VALUES(2, "555-1234")

SELECT MyLeft.*, MyRight.* FROM "MyLeft" JOIN "MyRight" ON LeftCode = RightCode
```

Whereas this query returns both records because the column type is VARCHAR.

```
CREATE CURSOR "MyLeft" (LeftPK I, LeftCode V(20))
INSERT INTO "MyLeft" VALUES(1, "351-561")
INSERT INTO "MyLeft" VALUES(2, "555-1234")

CREATE CURSOR "MyRight" (RightPK I, RightCode V(20))
INSERT INTO "MyRight" VALUES(1, "351-561-35C")
INSERT INTO "MyRight" VALUES(2, "555-1234")

SELECT MyLeft.*, MyRight.* FROM "MyLeft" JOIN "MyRight" ON LeftCode = RightCode
```

Comment: That's quite helpful to have the CHAR vs VARCHAR behavior explained. My original JOIN used alltrim() on both comparison values. That seems a bit misplaced now. It looks like == itself would have done the job.